# Easy Introduction to Representation Theory

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

I have a student that is interested in reading up on representation theory in her own time.  She knows a small amount of linear algebra, what you would expect in a simple sophomore linear algebra course.  She doesn't know what a direct sum is or any fields other than $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.  The books and online notes that I know are a little too high level for her.  Does anyone know any good (preferably free or cheap) notes for an undergraduate at her level to learn representations of finite groups?

Comment: How much does she know about finite groups?

Comment: The introduction to Representation Theory in Artin's Algebra wasn't too difficult of an introduction.  Not much field theory is given, and direct sums are introduced in the chapter.  Not too advanced of linear algebra is required (it doesn't talk about tensor products or anything on that level, which is a pity, but good for your student).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft She just did a summer research project where she had to learn what a finite group is and what a group action is.  She is currently in an introductory class on groups.